# Run a VM with GPU pass through

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, vmware, gpu, vmware-workstation

I really like some old games from Win98. Sadly a lot of them doesn't run on Windows 10 (x64) anymore.

So I decided to run something older (chose WinXP) in a VM.
I installed VMWare Workstation Player and created my VM, everything fine. I installed Anno 1602 and it ran a little bit laggy... OK. I installed black and white (which is a 3D game) and it was unplayable... Not OK.

I googled a lot but wasn't able to find information on how to pass a GPU in VMWare Workstation Player. All I could find was about vSphere. Then I started to search for VirtualBox. That's not what I want since I had a lot of trubble to work with VirtualBox. But also there I wasn't able to find something. I found something about an extension and a lot of linux commands, but sadly I haven't linux on my host, nor on my client. The last thing I found was about HyperV. Well I tried this and till today I wasn't able to pass the sound so also nope.

So here my question:

Is there a VM software that is (relatively) easy to use and which supports (also in a (relatively) easy way) to pass a GPU to the client?

Also if there is a way to do this in VMWare Workstation Player, please, please tell me! VMWare is the software that I can handle best.

Comment: Installed the VMWare guest additions software?

Comment: you mean VMWare Tools? Yes. But haven't found a way to pass a GPU with or without tools installed.

Comment: GPU passthrough isn't likely to help unless you can find drivers that will work. Most modern graphics cards won't have XP drivers in the first place and you need to have two graphics cards in the first place, either an integrated one as well as a dedicated card or two dedicated cards. Passthrough disconnects the card from your host and gives it to the guest, it is not a shared resource. Nothing in your question tells us you understand the implications of what you are doing or even if you can do it with your system in the first place. Passthrough depends on your processor and the VM software

Comment: I know. A friend has an old nVidia GPU so I have two GPUs (or will in a few days). But even if I already had the GPU I couldn't use it because I don't know _how_ to pass it.

Comment: I think it sounds like what you really want is GPU-based GPU emulation, because your XP VM won't be able to handle your modern GPU directly.  I haven't heard of that term before, but searching for it on Google found over 3 million hits, and some of the first page links looked potentially useful.

Comment: I'm taking about a gt 220. Isn't this old enough?

Comment: VMware Workstation and Player don't have PCI pass-through.  The closest you'll get on a type 2 hypervisor is VirtualBox on a Linux (not Windows) host. https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#pcipassthrough  Otherwise, you'll need to use something like KVM (Linux based type 1 hypervisor) that allows you to pass through a card. UnRAID uses this technology.  There are no Windows 10 hypervisors that do this.  Hyper-V has DDA, but that won't work with XP and requires the server version of Windows and workstation level video cards, among other hardware requirements.

Comment: So any other ideas to improve my 3d performance in my vm? I tried it with the win98 game "Star Trek Armada". After all guides I followed haven't worked was clear that there is no other way than running it in a VM.